# How to override defaut behaviour of checkbox

Tags: jquery

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8brm830z/1/

I want to make the present checkbox selected /unselecetd control it from the class formItem only .

When clicked on checkbox nothing should happen (that is I should not be selected and unselecetd)

HTML:

```
<form class="formItem">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="check4" data-mini="true" id_attr="4"  />
<label item_id_itr_some="label4" class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Popcorn Plain salted</label>
 <i class="delete-item-btn"></i>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".formItem", function() {        
    alert('clicked on formItem');    
});

$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) { 

});
```

I don't want to use disabled attribute of checkbox also .

When clicked on checkbox , i want to call the code present under the class FormItem .

Is that Possible ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tekhkjwp/2/

Comment: use event.preventDefault(); and remove alert

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `stopPropagation();` method

```
$(document).on("click", ".formItem", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();   
 });
```

[JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8brm830z/4/)**

```
$(this).prop('checked',!$(this).prop('checked'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the default functionality:

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

To make the checkbox work using `.formItem`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".formItem", function() {
  $('#check4').prop('checked',!$('#check4').is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the event's default behavior when you don't want the click to apply.

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) { 
 e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Here is a corrected jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/8brm830z/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".formItem", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();   
 });
```

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

In the case of a checkbox, the default action is to toggle selection.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/claudioredi/e28h9zx7/)

Answer (score 0):

Put `return false` in checkbox click event and check / uncheck it inside form click event.

```
$(document).on("click", ".formItem", function() {

alert('clicked on formItem');  
    $('#check4').prop('checked',!$('#check4').is(':checked'));
});


$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) { 
     return false;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/8brm830z/7/)**

Comment: Thank you very much , when checkbox is cliked on i want to call the code that is present under the class .formItem .